# How to clip the top bar with screen

Tags: html, css

How to clip my top bar with screen. So as I goes down on page i mean scrolling down the page the top bar should also move. Just like in Facebook the top bar moves on screen.
I am searching google from last 2 hours. But unable to get, that what we calls it.

[image]

and my HTML/CSS is ..

```
#topnavbar
{
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 background-image:url('top.jpg');
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

HTML

```
 <div id="topnavbar">

 </div>
```

Comment: Yeah at the moment you can call it header. Where I wrote top bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there are some sort of image slider on your page. So what I will suggest you to include **z-index** also.

```
#topnavbar
{
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 background-image:url('top.jpg');
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
 position:fixed;
 z-index:500;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're talking about fixing the position of the navbar to the top of the screen, right?

```
top:0;position:fixed;
```

-

```
#topnavbar {
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 background-image:url('top.jpg');
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
 top:0;
 position:fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In CSS, `position`ing elements is a fundamental concept. In this case, you want a `fixed` position. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), you should adhere to the following guidelines for `fixed` position elements:

> Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a
>   specified position relative to the screen's viewport and doesn't move
>   when scrolled. When printing, position it at that fixed position on
>   every page.

To reiterate, if you want to keep an element in the same position, regardless of where the page is scrolled, use `position:fixed`

```
#topnavbar{
    position:fixed;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/C5Uf4/)

Answer (score 1):

What you need to search for is how to use the css attribute `position: fixed;` to have a div or other element 'stay where you put it' relative to it's containing element.

Really quick and rough example:

http://jsfiddle.net/c93cK/